# default directory permissions redhat linux

Tags: unix, permissions, redhat-enterprise-linux

How can I set default group owner & permissions for any new file created under /data/user-name/ ?

I want any new file created under /data/user-name/ to have the following properties: 1) group owner = marketing 2) owner permissions = rwx 3) group permissions = rwx 4) other permissions = r--

```
touch /data/user-name/test.file
ls -lah /data/user-name/test.file
```

should produce

```
-rwxrwxr--  1 username marketing     0B Apr  7 13:23 test.file
```

I cannot figure out how to accomplish this. Thank you!!!

Comment: That would require you set those permissions on the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Ownership and permissions are inherited from the parent directory where a file is created.  So all you would need to do is apply the group:owner and the permissions rwxrwxr (or 774) to that parent directory and move on.

If you use SMB, it also has tooling to set permissions on any new file or folder but that's beyond the scope of your question.  I just thought I would mention in case it's useful.